# Setting hidden input value to a blob to be subbmited using form method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to submit a form with a blob appended to one of the hidden input tags like so.

```
<form method="POST" action="api/save/image">
   <input id="p_id" type="hidden" name="p_id" value=""/>
   <input id="image" type="hidden" name="image" value=""/>
   <button type="submit">Save Photo</button>
</form>
```

And my Javascript looks something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#p_id').val("444666"); //set hidden input

    var croppedPhoto = $('#crop_stage').cropper('getCroppedCanvas');
    croppedPhoto.toBlob(function (blob) {
          $('#image').val(blob); //set blob to form hidden input
    }

});
```

My issue is that I am unable to submit this because the blob isn't getting saved to the hidden field, instead it's the value [object Blob].

How do I append my blob so it can be submitted to the server?

Also please note that I am not able to use formData(); since I have to support IE8/IE9.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please provide a working example using a code snippet or [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: sure here you go https://jsfiddle.net/b69tcdnm/ there isn't much of a working example since that's the reason for this question.

Comment: You should take a look at the console. You have a couple errors.

Comment: @BaconJuice I have the same problem. Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: With this it should be possible to do it. This is a hack however, and will probably not work in all current browsers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119426/how-to-set-file-objects-and-length-property-at-filelist-object-where-the-files-a?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

this is an 8 years old question by now, and unfortunately I experienced the same thing..

And my solution was to replace `toBlob` with `toDataURL`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#p_id').val("444666"); //set hidden input

    var croppedPhoto = $('#crop_stage').cropper('getCroppedCanvas');
    $('#image').val(croppedPhoto.toDataURL); // set hidden input

});
```

That code untested yet because I not using jquery for long now..
In vanilla.js can be done with

```
let img = document.getElementById("image")
let data = croppedPhoto.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.9)
img.setAttribute("value", data)
```

Notice I use `setAttribute` instead of directly set `value` because that not work in my case somehow